# Shell Script improvement for getting diff result

Tags: shell, jenkins, coverity

I have shell Script written which does a job of comparing two files and and gives me result in a HTML format for defects. But i want to improve it so that i can only get modified files defects instead of legacy defects also. I am using this script to get Coverity report.

```
 while read line; do
n=$((++n))
if echo $line | grep '^[[:space:]]*>' &>/dev/null; then
    if [ $(($n % 2)) -eq 1 ]; then
        # TODO somehow get proper defect number from html
        # echo "Defect num: $(($n/2 + 1))"
        def_num=$((++def_num))
    fi
    echo $line | sed -n -e 's/>[[:space:]]*\(.*\)/\1/p'
    if [ $(($n % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "-------------------------------"
    fi


done < <(diff -y -W 200 ./cov-results-base/result.filt ./cov-results-changed/result.filt)

echo "==============================="
echo

echo "Number of defects in old code: $(tac cov-results-base/summary.xml |
                    sed -n '/num/{s|<num>\(.*\)</num>|\1|p; q;}')"
echo "Number of defects in new code: $(tac cov-results-changed/summary.xml |
                    sed -n '/num/{s|<num>\(.*\)</num>|\1|p; q;}')"
```

Comment: Are you asking if the file has been touched or if the content is different?

Comment: If the file has been touched or modified.

Answer (score 0):

This enables you to get the last modification time of a file and the compare with the current time.

```
now=`date +%s`
modified=`stat -c "%Y" $file`

if [ $(($now-$modified)) -gt 0 ]; then 
     echo "not modified"; 
else 
     echo "modified"; 
fi
```

I hope that this is what you wanted.

Comment: Does this work with HTML Parsing. I might asking wrong question. but my point is i wanna use HTML Parsing.

Comment: I am getting defects for modified files but the problem is i am also getting legacy defects also.

Comment: How would i improve my question ? My access is blocked.